# how can i delete a Facebook Test User with 2+ apps using the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When i try to delete the user like it says in the docs (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/#deleting) i get the error response :

```
(#2903) Cannot delete this test account because it is associated with other applications. Use DELETE app_id/accounts/test-users/test_account_id to remove it from other apps first. Use GET test_user_id/ownerapps to get complete list of owner apps.
```

then when i try to do what it says (replacing `<user_id>` and `<app_id>` with a facebook numeric id) :

```
DELETE <app_id>/accounts/test-users/<user_id> to remove it from other apps first
```

i get this error :

```
Unknown path components: /<user_id>
```

am i missing something ?

Comment: i've also created a bug with facebook.com here http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194903963919864

Answer (score 1):

As the error said you cannot delete an user because it has been assigned to two or more application.

The workaround for this is to get all the applications which are using this specific user using this call

"https://graph.facebook.com/TEST_ACCOUNT_ID/ownerapps&access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN"

This will give you the list of app the test account is attached to prior decoding the object with a JSON serializer. Then you can **remove** and not delete the test account from each app until only one remains using :

"https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?uid=TEST_ACCOUNT_ID&access_token=APPLICATION_ACCESS_TOKEN&method=delete"

When only one app remains you can **delete** the test account using :

"https://graph.facebook.com/TEST_ACCOUNT_ID?method=delete&access_token=TEST_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_TOKEN"

Hope this help!

Comment: i have not had a change to try this out yet, but are you saying the key to avoiding the error response is to not use the "remove" link `https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users/TEST_ACCOUNT_ID ...` but to use the form of the link you provided `https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?uid=TEST_ACCOUNT_ID ...` ?  The key difference being how you pass thru the `TEST_ACCOUNT_ID`

Comment: What I tried to say is that you need to remove the test account from all the apps he's bond to then you can delete it.

Comment: ahh, that's the root of my problem. i cannot "remove" the user from an app using the URL the "delete" endpoint responds with : `https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users/TEST_USER_ID&access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN` . And i noticed in your response that the "remove" should be called like this : `https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/accounts/test-users?uid=TEST_USER_ID&access_token=YOUR_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN` . the key being how TEST_USER_ID is being passed in